# How to inverse an arrow in chemfig?

Tags: arrows, chemfig, chemistry

Here's a scheme in chemfig:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
        \schemestart
        \ce{\textbf{E}}\arrow{->[][\scriptsize{\ce{CaF2, H2SO4}}]}[120]
        \ce{\textbf{F}}\arrow{->[\scriptsize{\ce{AlCl3}}]}[40]
        \ce{\textbf{B}}\arrow{-U>[*{0}\ce{H2O}][*{0}\ce{D}]}[90]
        \textbf{C}
        \arrow(@c3--){-U>[\ce{CH3OH}][\ce{D}]}[0,2]
        \ce{\textbf{G}}\arrow{->[\scriptsize{\ce{NaH}}]}
        \ce{\textbf{H}}\arrow{->[\scriptsize{\ce{H2SO4}}]}
        \ce{Na2SO4}, \ce{\textbf{K}}, \ce{\textbf{I}}
        \arrow(@c1--){->[\scriptsize{$t^o$}]} %here
        \ce{\textbf{C}}
        \schemestop
        \bigskip 
\end{document}
```

I need to inverse the direction of the arrow from c1 to c8 (i.e. from E to C: marked in the code). How can I make the arrow go from C to E?

Comment: I can't run your code but have you tried using `<-` instead of `->`?

Answer (score 5):

The code doesn't compile as is and not only because of the missing `\begin{document}`. The command `\ce` is from `mhchem` and also `chemmacros` is not loaded that could afford compatibility, but is needed anyway.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

%\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \ch{\textbf{E}}\arrow{->[][\scriptsize{\ch{CaF2, H2SO4}}]}[120]
  \ch{\textbf{F}}\arrow{->[\scriptsize{\ch{AlCl3}}]}[40]
  \ch{\textbf{B}}\arrow{-U>[*{0}\ch{H2O}][*{0}\ch{D}]}[90]
  \textbf{C}
  \arrow(@c3--){-U>[\ch{CH3OH}][\ch{D}]}[0,2]
  \ch{\textbf{G}}\arrow{->[\scriptsize{\ch{NaH}}]}
  \ch{\textbf{H}}\arrow{->[\scriptsize{\ch{H2SO4}}]}
  \ch{Na2SO4}, \ch{\textbf{K}}, \ch{\textbf{I}}
  \arrow(@c1--){<-[\scriptsize{$t^o$}]} %here
  \ch{\textbf{C}}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Note `<-` instead of `->` for the requested direction and `\ch` instead of `\ce`.

[image]